# tiniMCE do not init in a jsPanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I use jsPanel to have kind of modal windows appearing on my site.

On jsPanel init, I specify content with a textarea, and a callback function.

Once my jsPanel is created, I try to initialise a tinyMCE in the callback. I test tinyMCE instances and my editor is in the listing of instances... but in the jsPanel it displays as a normal textarea, not as a tinyMCE.

Any idea ?
Here is the code :

```
function oninitjspanel()
{
    console.log('before init modal mce');
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#email_message",
        entity_encoding : "raw",
        encoding: "UTF-8",
        theme: "modern",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
        "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
        "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
    });
    console.log('after init modal mce');
    for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(i + " Editor id:", tinymce.editors[i].id);
    }  
}

$('#new_document').click (function () {
    var content = '<div id="choix_document"><textarea id="email_message"></textarea></div>';                
    $.jsPanel({
        content:        content,
        position:       "center",
        theme:          "success",
        title:          "Nouveau document/email",
        size:           {   width:  function(){ return $(window).width()*0.75 }, 
                            height: function(){ return $(window).height()*0.75 } },
        toolbarFooter:  "<div class='email_submit'>Envoyer email</div><div id='email_returnmessage'></div>",
        callback:       oninitjspanel(),
    });

});
```

The console log :

```
before init modal mce
after init modal mce
0 Editor id: model_editor
1 Editor id: email_message
```

EDIT : one more thing, as tinyMCE have focus issues in modals, I apply at my page loading the following to prevent the issue :

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".mce-window, .moxman-window").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a look at https://github.com/Flyer53/jsPanel/issues/51

But I guess you're the one asking the same question on GitHub's the jsPanel issues page anyhow?